# Adding background music to a webpage

Tags: html, audio, xampp

How to add background music to my website?

Also how to continue the music in next page while I am navigating to other pages in my site?

I am using xampp.

Comment: I am creating  website using xampp.

Answer (score 0):

According to W3Schools, "The `<embed>` tag is supported in all major browsers." So, you can use `<embed>` instead of the `<audio>` tag.

```
   <embed src="audio.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" width="2" height="0">
   </embed>
   <noembed>
      <bgsound src="audio.mp3" loop="infinite">
   </noembed>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, you should have a look on http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

It's nothing, which is directly connected to XAMPP. It is more a thing of your website itself. 
You can also use a webkit to play the music, not only HTML5, but this depends on your own decision.
But think about this: When you have a reload, or a change to a different html (or whatever) document, which isn't in a frame, the whole page will reload and the player will start from the beginning.

My idea would be, to have all "pages" on one, like a list, and setting anchors to the specific region of your site. Or you could use frames and get your music-player in the outer region of the site (not in the "page space", which will be changed - this will also cause a reload).